# attach with gdb after dropping privileges

Tags: capabilities

Under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I cannot seem to debug a once-privileged process for love or money as an unprivileged user.

The file is setgid (mode 2755).  It forks, and the child:

1. releases its capabilities
2. calls `setgid(getgid())`

Yet, gdb cannot attach to it when running under the same uid and gid.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
0

$ echo $(id -nu) $(id -ng)
jklowden jklowden

$ ps -p 18272 -o user,group,euser,egroup,ruser,rgroup
USER     GROUP    EUSER    EGROUP   RUSER    RGROUP
jklowden jklowden jklowden jklowden jklowden jklowden

$ gdb -q -p 18272
Attaching to process 18272
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
```

What am I missing?

I have also tried to attack this by raising my own capabilities, with some success, although I'm not sure it's the "right" answer.

```
$ cat /etc/security/capability.conf
CAP_SYS_PTRACE jklowden

$ sudo setcap CAP_SYS_PTRACE=pe  $(which gdb)
```

That allows gdb to attach to the process.  But it does so by increasing what gdb can do, not decreasing what the process requires.

In case it's interesting, the file's setgid id is not root, but an unprivileged group that gives it access to a group-writable directory.  Users of the application similarly belong to the same group, but forked child processes don't require access to that directory.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe the real (as opposed to effective) GID is different and you need to drop it as well? According to the manpage on my system (which is 1804 but probably close enough), `setgid` only sets the effective GID. Try `gid_t gid = getgid(); setregid(gid, gid)`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it.  I didn't modify the code, but updated my question to show that ps(1) reports rgroup and ruser are also correct.  But your question did force me to read that man page again, and realize that group and egroup are the same.  :-)

Comment: Solved: [ptrace fails with yama/ptrace_scope=0](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1860822) TL;DR, a setgid process is not dumpable, and thus cannot be attached to.  fork(2) doesn't change that.  Resetting the gid etc. are necessary but insufficient.  Once that's done, use prctl(2) to set the process to be dumpable.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and not in a comment